# extra side menu in codename one app

Tags: android, io, codenameone, side-menu

In my app I have a right hand side menu. But there also seems to be a left hand side menu, only containing the back button.
There is no menu button (with three horizontal lines), but if you touch the left edge of the screen and drag in the menu appears.
I can't see why it's being created, but is that any way to disable or remove it?

Comment: I'm guessing you added the side menu bar manually in the old approach. We recommend using the `Toolbar` class which makes all of this work seamlessly